# Can a coroutine suspend and then resume on a different thread? Are the memory effects of the first thread carried to the second thread?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Consider

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runBlocking {
        launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            var a = 0
            a++
            delay(100)
            println(a)
        }
    }
}
```

Since the Dispatcher has multiple threads, is it possible for the program to change threads at the suspending `delay` function? Is it guaranteed that it will print '1' or does `a` need to be `AtomicInteger`?

Comment: I don't have any documentation to support this claim, but I believe coroutines provide happens-before guarantees in such cases.

Comment: @broot I found some official linked from the duplicate question: https://proandroiddev.com/what-is-concurrent-access-to-mutable-state-f386e5cb8292

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After execution of the `suspend delay()` function there is a possibility that the coroutine will continue execution on another thread from the `Dispatchers.Default` thread pool.

There is no need in additional synchronization for `a` variable, because it is being used only within one coroutine, code within a coroutine executes sequentially, providing happens-before guarantees. If the variable was used within a couple of coroutine than additional synchronization would be needed.